# Laravel 4 - view is not rendering

Tags: php, laravel

Simple view not rendering:

```
public function getFranchise() {

    echo 'getFranchise';

    $franchiseData['shopViews'] = array(1 => 'a');
    $franchiseData['aaa'] = 'bbb';
    return View::make('test.filteredData.franchise', $franchiseData);
}
```

view in test/filteredData/franchise.blade.php

```
franchise

{{--$shopsViews}}  {{-- Fatal error: Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an       exception in D:\projektai\dashboard\app\storage\views\d2973247ea68aed2fdfd33dc19cccada on line 5}}

{{ $aaa }} 

@foreach ($shopsViews as $shop)
<strong>aaa</strong>
@endforeach
```

Only word getFranchise is displayed which means controller function is called. No any errors, no anything. WHat is that?

Even in constructor is added

```
ini_set("display_errors", true);
```

**Edited**

Found that this:

```
{{--$shopsViews}}  {{-- Fatal error: Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception in D:\projektai\dashboard\app\storage\views\d2973247ea68aed2fdfd33dc19cccada on line 5}}
```

comment was causing stop of execution in the script. WHy is that? this is valid laravel comment. Also I noticed weird thigs when I comment

```
 <?php //print_r ?>
```

then it shows something like web page not found, like interent connection has gone. I dont get at all whats happening with commenting.

Answer (score 2):

Your blade view must contain @extends() and @section() to work in this case.
And comment should look like this {{-- $shopsViews --}}. That should fix your problem.

```
@extends('your_layout_folder.layout')

@section('content')
 @foreach ($shopsViews as $shop)
 <strong>aaa</strong>
 @endforeach
@stop
```

Please follow the documentation! http://laravel.com/docs

Comment: interesting. I read the docs, but I thought its not necessary to extend. I dont want to. But if thats the only solution, then I will have to consider. BTw comment you wrote the same I was writing, didn't you? I mean {{-- $shopsViews --}}

Comment: oh, I just noticed that there are needed dashes at the end. I thought its like in sql - only dashes at the beginning.